# "Labelling" UnityEvent parameters so when creating listeners, it's easier to see a description of parameter

Tags: unity-game-engine, events

My overarching goal: Create a UnityEvent with, lets say, two parameters. An incoming object and an outgoing object. When I add a listener on another script and create the function it executes when the event is fired, I want to be able to write that code without having to bounce back over to where the event was invoked in order to figure out which order my parameters are in.

I know what you might be thinking: Just "remember" or go back to your other code; But I've got the attention span of a fish 75% of the time and the patience of a toddler who hasn't eaten in 6 hours (a joke). I simply continue to wonder if there is an easier way to do this because Visual Studio and Unity's monobehaviour functions do something similar when you start typing a function - I'm referring to VS's tooltip as you start typing parameters in a function that describe what that parameter type is referring to in the context of the program. (I'll explain)

I can't seem to find the right google search terms to find this answer if it does already exist and it's possible this is something in Visual Studio specifically instead of something related to unity.

Also, I personally love resources (being taught how to fish) as opposed to a granular direct solution (being given a fish), so if you have any to share for this specifically they are absolutely welcome.

This obviously isn't my exact code because my exact code isn't clean, but this is the gist of what I'm doing so there's some additional context behind the variables I'm referring to.

```
public class SceneLoader : MonoBehavior
{
     public UnityEvent <Scene, Scene> OnSceneChange;
     private int targetSceneIndex;

     public void InvokeTheSceneChange()
     {
          Scene outoingScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
          Scene incomingScene = SceneManager.GetSceneAt(targetSceneIndex);
          //scene change logic
          OnSceneChange?.Invoke(outgoingScene, incomingScene);
     }
}
```

```
public class Menu : MonoBehavior
{
     private SceneLoader sceneLoader;

     private void OnEnable()
     {
          sceneLoader.OnSceneChange.AddListener(SomeFunction);
     }
     
     // SPECIFIC QUESTION: Is there a way to customize the default parameter names here when 
     // creating this function through VS's intellicode so it doesn't default to arg[param index]?
     // Or is there otherwise a way to do some sort of tooltip like the SomeOtherFunction below
     // does through that summary comment? 
     // That <summary></summary> comment leads me to believe that this MIGHT be possible. 
     private void SomeFunction(Scene arg0, Scene arg1)
     {
          sceneLoader.OnSceneChange.AddListener(SomeFunction);
     }

    /// <summary>
    /// Description of the function 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="arg0">Parameter description 1</param>
    /// <param name="arg1">Parameter description 2</param>
     private void SomeOtherFunction(Scene arg0, Scene arg1)
     {
          sceneLoader.OnSceneChange.AddListener(SomeFunction);
     }

}
```

I'm honestly trying help my ADHD brain stay on task and help me remember which parameter goes where. If not possible, would also be okay hearing that so I stop going down a rabbit hole.

Comment: Not sure if that is possible or not.  You can put a summary tag on the event and list the params there eg `/// <summary>arg0: scene out, arg1: scene in</summary>`.  Then when you type the event it shows up.